# Looking for OID values for Xerox's fuser and transfer roll

Tags: snmp, mib, xerox

I'm trying to get SNMP OID's values for maximum and current capacity of transfer roller and fuser.

I'm pretty sure that is it:

- Maximum capacity:

.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.10 - transfer roller (-2)

.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8.1.12 - fuser (-2)

- Current capacity:

.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.10 - transfer roller (-3)

.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9.1.12 - fuser (-3)

The problem is that these values don't change even if printer says that these materials need to be replaced.

How can I get the status of these?

Comment: Please contact the printer vendor technical support for assistance.

Comment: I did and they did not respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OIDs you provided are from the [Printer-MIB](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1759). `.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.8` is `prtMarkerSuppliesMaxCapacity`, and `.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.11.1.1.9` is `prtMarkerSuppliesLevel`, and the two index sub-identifiers are `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceIndex` and `prtMarkerSuppliesIndex`. You can confirm that they correspond to the components you think they do by checking `prtMarkerSuppliesDescription`.

To answer your question, the description of `prtMarkerSuppliesLevel` says

> The value (-1) means other and specifically indicates that the sub-unit places no restrictions on this parameter.  The value (-2) means unknown.  A value of (-3) means that the printer knows that there is some supply/remaining space, respectively.

The description also seems to imply that positive (maybe non-negative) numbers should only be used if the printer has a reliable way to measure them. The best explanation I can think of is that your printer *can* detect that these supplies are low, and uses that to gauge when they need to be replaced, but cannot measure the exact level reliably enough to support positive values for this SNMP object. There is no negative value to say "in need of replacement", and 0 is presumably reserved for "empty" (which it may not ever reach), so it just keeps showing -3.